# What is the difference between getPageLabels and getPageLabelFormats?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I have a program that calls `PdfPageLabels.getPageLabels()` and 
`PdfPageLabels.getPageLabelFormats()` on the same `PdfReader` object on 
successive lines of my code:

```
PdfPageLabels.PdfPageLabelFormat[] pplf =  PdfPageLabels.getPageLabelFormats(reader);
String[] labs = PdfPageLabels.getPageLabels(reader);
```

I would have expected the two calls always to return arrays of the same length, they are supposed to be the same labels. This is true most of the time, but occasionally this is NOT the case.

I have an example. It's a 150Mb PDF file which appears to have 4670 labels via `getPageLabels()`, but only 1 via `getPageLabelFormats()`.

So my question is: Under what circumstances could the two calls return arrays of different lengths?

Comment: I'm not sure why this is down-voted. I even see a close vote "because the question is unclear." I think the question is very clear, although rather trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between both methods is simple:

- `getPageLabels()` returns the label of every page in an array. If your PDF has 4670 pages, you will get an array with 4670 `String` values.
- `getPageLabelFormat()` returns an array with the formats that are used in the document. It doesn't return `String` values, but `PdfPageLabelFormat` instances. In many cases, there is only one page label format used throughout the document.

**For example:**

You have a document with an intro of five pages, numbered *i*, *ii*, *iii*, *iv* and *v*. Then you have a hundred pages, numbers 1 to 100.

In this case, `getPageLabels()` should return an array with 105 `String` values. The `getPageLabelFormat()` method however, will only return two `PageLabelFormat` values because we are only using two page label formats:

- one saying that the first physical page starts with lowercase roman numbers starting with *i*.
- one saying that the sixth physical page starts with arabic numbers, starting with 1.

Only the start format is needed, physical page 2 to 4 have the same format as physical page 1; physical page 7 to 105 have the same format as page 6.

Comment: Brilliant - thank you! And also for endorsing the clarity of my question.

Comment: By the way, can I assume that the _i_ th label returned by `getPageLabels()` corresponds to the _i_ th physical page - counting from zero?

Comment: Answering from my phone: the array starts with *i = 0* and gives you the label of the first page. So yes, counting from zero, you are correct.

Comment: Together your comment answer about the page label array matching the physical pages, and your main answer, have led to a much better implementation of my program. Thanks.